# Can a multithreaded function use a static array to share data between threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

Say you have a function that counts the occurences of a value in a large array. You want to multithread this function by having each thread count the occurences in its own part of the array, then adding the results together. We can assume that each thread has a unique rank (from 0 to N-1), and that each thread will call the function at about the same time. E.g.:

```
int count[N];  // global array

int countOccurences()
{
    count[rank] = /* count occurences in one part of the array */
    // wait until all other threads reached this point
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        total += count[i];
    return total;
}
```

The question is, in the above example, could I move the `count` array into the body of `countOccurences()` as a static variable? I don't need it to exist anywhere outside the function body: will a static array be shared among threads?

Comment: I would expect performance glitch with this case on modern hardware since continuous static array will be likely placed on a single numa node so all threads will access to the memory of a single NUMA node thus making a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, threads have access to global data and static data in the same compilation unit, but there is more to this topic about "sharing data between threads" that is important to understand.

For each thread, there is a corresponding function (the "thread function") that a thread will execute in parallel with other threads. A thread has access to whatever that function can access, either through pointer or reference parameters, global data, static data in the same compilation unit as the thread function, or global and/or static data that is readable/modifiable via other functions that the thread function can call. You should be able to determine every memory region that a given function can read or modify. Those memory regions of a given thread function are exactly the memory regions that the thread has access to.

It is easy to see that global data and static data in the same compilation unit are accessible to a thread function, so that's why the answer to your question is "yes".

One thing that you might want to look into is OpenMP, which has built-in constructs for parallelizing a `countOccurrences` operation (a so-called "reduction"):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t countOccurrences(const int *arr, size_t n, int which) {
    size_t count, i;

    count = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == which)
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3, 5, -1, -1, 0 };

    size_t count = countOccurrences(arr, sizeof (arr)/sizeof (arr[0]), -1);
    printf("count = %d\n", (int) count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can, because your threads finish their work before you return from your `countOccurences`. just pass reference to i-th element to i-th thread function so it can access it

something like this:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void thread_function(int& result)
{
    // your implementation
}

size_t const n = 100;

int countOccurences()
{
    int count[n];
    boost::thread_group group;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        group.create_thread(boost::bind(thread_function, boost::ref(count[i])));
    group.join_all();
    return std::accumulate(count, count + n, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't entirely clear in the question. `countOccurences()` would already be inside the thread function.